# How to rename a slave node in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, virtual-machine, master-slave

In jenkins I am using master slave architecture to dynamically deploy a slave machine and perform some operations on it. I want to deploy different jobs on different Virtual Machine(slaves) having same environment( i.e slave having same label). To do this possible solution is that I rename a slave node, thus a new instance with same environment is created when a I want to deploy a new job.So my question is how to rename a slave in such a situation?